# How to override style inheritance?

Tags: html, css

Q: How can I override the font size for custom table classes so that they don't pick up the inherited value?

```
table {
    font-size: 1.09em;
    /* other stuff... */  
}

table.order
{
    font-size: 0.75 em;  /* font isn't getting set....it's picking up the 1.09em from the above table */
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a space between `0.75` and `em`. Remove it and the style should be set correctly (assuming the table actually has a `class` of `order`).